# Desativar quebra de linha no phpstorm

Tags: php, phpstorm

Gostaria de saber como desativar a quebra de linha PHPStorm.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Isso se chama *wrap*. Talvez esta pergunta te ajude: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10351608/1452488.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na barra de menus, procure pela opção 'View' -> 'Active Editor' -> 'Use Soft Wraps'. Porém, isso vai funcionar somente para o arquivo que estiver aberto.

Caso você queira manter essa opção no editor de forma geral (para todos os arquivos), então você têm que configurar em Preferences -> General -> Na aba, você desabilita a opção 'Use Soft Wraps in Editor'.

Comment: Tem como deixar definitivo? Percebo que ao abrir o programa novamente, sempre volta marcado a opção.

Comment: Cara, eu não vou saber te responder. Até procurei por uma solução aqui e tentei reproduzir o seu cenário.

Comment: Ao abrir o programa novamente, a opção continua desmarcada aqui pra mim. O que pode estar acontecendo é um reset ao alternar entre projetos.

Comment: Algumas configurações ficam salvas somente para o projeto que você configurou. Eu sei que tem como definir essas configurações para padronizar em todos os projetos, mas não lembro de cabeça como eu defini isso agora.